# Flutter:How to solve system can not find the path Specified

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, mobile, firebase-storage

I have been working on a flutter app and recently installed three firebase related pacakges firebase_core,cloud_firestore and firebase_storage. But after installation when I try to import them in a .dart file I am facing 'The system cannot find the path specified

import 'package:quiver/core.dart';' error. So what should I do ,here is my pubspec.yaml file . I even tried adding quiver to the pubspec.yaml if that could fix the erro but it didn't.

```
name: bookecommerceapp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.22.6

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_fonts: any
  http: ^0.12.2
  provider: ^4.3.3
  search_page: ^1.4.0
  loading: ^1.0.2
  file_picker: ^2.1.6
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0+1
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
  quiver: ^2.1.5


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
    - google_fonts/
#    - imagesa_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  fonts:
    - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: google_fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
        - asset: google_fonts/OpenSans-Bolditalic.ttf
        - asset: google_fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf
        - asset: google_fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
        - asset: google_fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf
        - asset: google_fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf

  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

and here is my full error stacktrace

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-7.0.0/lib/firebase_storage.dart:11:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/quiver-2.1.5/lib/core.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:quiver/core.dart';
       ^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:10:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/quiver-2.1.5/lib/core.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:quiver/core.dart';
       ^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart:15:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/quiver-2.1.5/lib/core.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:quiver/core.dart';
       ^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-7.0.0/lib/src/firebase_storage.dart:168:23: Error: The method 'hash2' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseStorage'.
 - 'FirebaseStorage' is from 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-7.0.0/lib/firebase_storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hash2'.
  int get hashCode => hash2(app.name, bucket);
                      ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-7.0.0/lib/src/reference.dart:211:23: Error: The method 'hash2' isn't defined for the class 'Reference'.
 - 'Reference' is from 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-7.0.0/lib/firebase_storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hash2'.
  int get hashCode => hash2(storage, fullPath);
                      ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-7.0.0/lib/src/task_snapshot.dart:49:23: Error: The method 'hash2' isn't defined for the class 'TaskSnapshot'.
 - 'TaskSnapshot' is from 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-7.0.0/lib/firebase_storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hash2'.
  int get hashCode => hash2(storage, ref);
                      ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:65:23: Error: The method 'hash2' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseApp'.
 - 'FirebaseApp' is from 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/firebase_core.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hash2'.
  int get hashCode => hash2(name, options);
                      ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/src/firebase_exception.dart:63:12: Error: The method 'hash3' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseException'.
 - 'FirebaseException' is from 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hash3'.
    return hash3(plugin, code, message);
           ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/src/firebase_options.dart:183:12: Error: The method 'hashObjects' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseOptions'.
 - 'FirebaseOptions' is from 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hashObjects'.
    return hashObjects(asMap.entries);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_firebase_app.dart:64:23: Error: The method 'hash2' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAppPlatform'.
 - 'FirebaseAppPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hash2'.
  int get hashCode => hash2(name, options);
                      ^^^^^
```

P.s The error happens when I only import it in any file like this

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
```

Comment: `hash2()` is from `quiver` package that's not related to the `firebase` packages. Did you put `import 'package:quiver/core.dart';` in your file? Btw, you'll need to run `flutter pub get` then rebuild your app after adding a new package. Hot reload won't allow you to use the new package immediately

Comment: I tried that and did not work . I even to create another app and showed me the same error message so I re-installed flutter and it is working now.

Comment: Problem was solved when upgrading the flutter version and clearing the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue as well and came about several situations that could cause it.

**First one:** It could be a broken path in your env variables. You can check all paths by doing a simple "echo %PATH%" in your terminal and removing those that don't point to a valid location.

**Second one:** Make sure that your project path doesn't include an '&' as stated on this issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41547

**Third one:** Another one that I found is that after uninstalling Anaconda it left out an AutoRun key in the command processor registry (in your case it may have been Firebase).

Check these places in regedit for broken links:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor

Comment: Thank you.  The (Third one) fixed my problem .

Comment: I've had "The system cannot find the path specified" popping up all over the place - no. 3 sorted it for me too - I would have never have thought of looking there!

Comment: how do I know there's broken link in point #3?

Answer (score -2):

First create a new folder in any drive you want, for example, `D:\` drive then paste the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore D:\Newfolder\bingnotes.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias bingnotes
```